# Adding files to the runtimes folder when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core website that uses `System.Management.Automation` so that I can fetch printers from remote printer servers. For this to work, I need the module PrintManagement that I manually added in `myproject\bin\Debug\net5.0\runtimes\win\lib\net5.0\Modules`.

I need this module to also be present when I publish the website to my server, but its not present.

From my understanding, Visual Studio uses its own virtual file system for this located at `myproject\runtimes\win\lib\net5.0\Modules\`.

Can I add files to this virtual folder and can I publish them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework in question, but in general, you do this in Visual Studio through the "Copy to Output" and "Build Action" properties of the item in the solution explorer... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by applying the following code to my .csproj file :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Infrastructure\Modules\PrintManagement\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>runtimes\win\lib\net5.0\Modules\PrintManagement\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to publish some files together? You can right-click the file you want to publish together and select `Properties`, and then select `Copy always` for `Copy to Output Directory`:
[image]

Then you can see this in you .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Your Path\Your File">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

For more details, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#include-files).